# Ios Onesignal & AlamoFireImage Podfile issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, onesignal

I am trying to get the correct dependencies installed into my podfile in order to run my application.  I need both AlamoFireImage and OneSignal pods, but am unable to download them both as needed because of a versioning issue.

Below is what I have for them in my podfile:

```
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
```

Below is the error I get when I run `pod install` :

```
[!] The following pods are integrated into targets that do not have the same Swift version:

    - Alamofire required by Phlare (Swift 3.0), OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (Swift 4.0)
    - AlamofireImage required by Phlare (Swift 3.0), OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (Swift 4.0)

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `9.3` on target `Phlare` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

These are the pod file install instructions suggested by both tutorials, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: are you developing in swift 3 or 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your pod file like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Phlare' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
        end
        if target.name == 'OneSignal'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```